# LineageOS build fails on macOS 10.14: Ninja Failed with Exit Status 1

Tags: android, android-source, ninja

I am building LineageOS(a fork of AOSP), on my own gerrit server. Upon building, a signed build using the command: `mka target-files-package otatools`.

I've tried looking online, but nobody seems to have posted something with an error as such. I've tried to make the module, but I dont know where it is located.

Here is the error log:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
LINEAGE_VERSION=16.0-20190501-UNOFFICIAL-sailfish
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_sailfish
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=kryo
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=kryo
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-18.5.0-x86_64-10.14.4
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ2A.190405.003
OUT_DIR=/Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out
============================================
[1/1] /Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/soong/.minibootstrap/min...p /Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninj
[55/56] glob prebuilts/ndk/stl.bp
[80/80] /Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build /Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/soong/build.ninja
/Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/build-lineage_sailfish-target-files-package-cleanspec.ninja is missing, regenerating...
/Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/build-lineage_sailfish-target-files-package.ninja is missing, regenerating...
[2/1030] including art/Android.mk ...
art/build/Android.common.mk:50: warning: unsupported HOST_ARCH=x86_64
[1030/1030] including vendor/qcom/opensource/dataservices/Android.mk ...
art/build/Android.gtest.mk:121: warning: overriding commands for target `Uncompressed'
art/build/Android.gtest.mk:101: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Uncompressed'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/target/product/sailfish/vendor/lib/hw/audio.primary.msm8996.so'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/target/product/sailfish/vendor/lib/hw/audio.primary.msm8996.so'
[ 99% 802/803] glob vendor/qcom/opensource/interfaces/wifi/supplicant/2.0/src
ninja: error: '/Volumes/blink/blinkBuild/out/host/darwin-x86/bin/verity_verifier', needed by 'otatools', missing and no known rule to make it
16:51:49 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (02:08 (mm:ss)) ####
```

It should just build. I've made the external drive APFS Case-Sensitive and added 10.14 as an option in the file, but it still fails with this build. Than you for the help!